# Could electroweak interactions derive from higgsing of gauged chiral symmetry?

Tags: gauge-theory, higgs, symmetry-breaking, beyond-the-standard-model, electroweak

[A recent question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/472637/embedding-of-su2-l-times-u1-y-into-su2-l-times-su2-r-in-electrowea) discussed the practice of introducing electroweak interactions into chiral perturbation theory by gauging part of the chiral symmetry. Gauging chiral symmetry is normally regarded as a formal trick, but I have noticed e.g. in holographic QCD that the flavor symmetry is genuinely gauged in the extra dimensions. Could the electroweak interactions be the low-energy remnant of genuinely gauged chiral or flavor symmetries?