# Custodial Symmetries of the standard model

Tags: symmetry, resource-recommendations, standard-model, gauge-theory

Recently I came across this concept in a paper and would like to know more about it. My problem is that in all the textbooks that I have seen none cover this topic. I would like the communities help regarding some resources for the same.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/473175/66086).

Answer (score 1):

Most good textbooks cover this topic, in fact, but not in great depth; they assume you have done the due diligence in studying and understanding papers of that era, the early 80s.

My own very top reference is [A Longhitano's thesis paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(81)90109-7), ***Low-energy impact of a heavy Higgs boson sector***, *Nucl Phys* **B188** (1981) 118-154, which, as such, goes into more explicit detail. Slug through and understand in detail his meticulous exposition. In particular, appreciate the rewriting of the Higgs doublet as a redundant 2×2 complex matrix, instead of a complex 2-spinor, which opens up the symmetry structure of the SU(2)×SU(2) involved.