# Trying to figure out what Zee is going for in Group Theory in a Nutshell for Physicists IV.7 exercise 3?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, group-theory, lie-algebra

I'm teaching using A. Zee's book, Group Theory in a Nutshell for Physicists. I'm thinking about assigning exercise 3 in chapter IV.7 because it looks like a good way for the students to practice working with subgroups, but the way Zee phrases the exercise it sounds like students are supposed to notice something deeper and I can't figure out what it is.

The problem concerns the local isomorphism between $SO(4)$ and $SU(2)\times SU(2)$. Zee makes this isomorphism explicit by writing,

\begin{equation}
W\rightarrow U^\dagger W V
\end{equation}

where $U$ and $V$ are $SU(2)$ matrices and $W=t I+i \vec{x}\cdot\vec{\sigma}$.

Zee talks about the diagonal subgroup $(V,V)$ in the text, and shows that it corresponds to the $SO(3)$ that rotates $\vec{x}$ and leaves $t$ fixed. Then, in the exercise he asks,

> What does the $SU(2)$ subgroup of $SO(4)$, consisting of the elements $(V^\dagger,V)$, correspond to? Verify that these transformations do change $t$.

Does anyone have any idea what this subgroup is supposed to correspond to? It's straightforward enough to work out a generic group element (and confirm that $t$ is transformed), but it doesn't seem very illuminating.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28505/2451 and links therein.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/547762/66086), and also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/472722/66086).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to stay out of transduction of pettifoggery, but here is what I would teach my students, in your place.
For *U,V,W* elements of SU(2), and likewise for their adjoints,
\begin{equation}
W\rightarrow U^\dagger W V
\end{equation}
is, indeed, an (2)×(2) transformation. To the extent the *U*s and the *V*s are unlinked to each other, they close into the left and right SU(2), respectively.

Now, as he says, the diagonal restriction *U=V* is an SU(2) subgroup, all right,
$$
W\rightarrow V_1^\dagger W V_1 \rightarrow V_2^\dagger V_1^\dagger W V_1 V_2 =  (V_1 V_2)^\dagger W (V_1 V_2),
$$
and, in [current algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_algebra#Example), is referred to as the Vector (isospin) subgroup.

That is, your students must see how the sum of the left and right generators of the *U*s and *V*, respectively, dubbed $\vec v\cdot \vec\sigma$, commute among themselves to a  $i(\vec v_1\times \vec v_2)\cdot\vec\sigma$.  The above map is called "adjoint action", and rotates the triplet $\vec x$, even though, superficially, they might think the σs can only rotate doublets.

***However***, for
$$
W\rightarrow V_1  W V_1 \rightarrow V_2  V_1  W V_1 V_2 \neq  (V_1 V_2)  W (V_1 V_2),
$$
so these SU(2) group elements do not close to a subgroup of the chiral (2)×(2). (They are in the (2)×(2)/(2) coset space, but no matter.)

Lie-algebraically, they are generated by left-minus-right generators, and are called the axial generators, $\vec a\cdot\vec\sigma$. The commutator of two such axials, as they should expect, is *not* an axial, but, instead, a vector generator, $i(\vec a_1\times \vec a_2))\cdot\vec\sigma$, the conceptual cornerstone of chiral dynamics. The fact they transform (shift) *t* is the reason they are said to realize the axials nonlinearly (~break chiral symmetry spontaneously).

So, if they do the problem, the good ones will balk at the specious subgroup thing.

Comment: Ah, I had the vague inkling this couldn't possibly be a subgroup but kept thinking "oh, but Zee directly says it is...", should have realized it would be an un-caught error.

Comment: ...been catching those in Tony's lectures since Spring of '74...