# Chiral Lagrangian Field

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, gauge-theory, chirality, sigma-models

In the chiral model $SU(N)_R × SU(N)_L$ with gauged Left-handed $SU(N)$, we take as the field the $SU(N)_L$-valued $\Sigma (x)$, defined as
$$\Sigma(x) = \exp\big( \frac{2i}{v} \chi^a(x)T^a\big).$$

What is the reason for which, in the chiral lagrangian, we take the exponential field $\Sigma (x)$ defined this way, instead of a "Yang Mills"-like,
$$\Sigma(x) = c \chi^a (x)T^a ,$$
with $c$ a suitable constant.

Is there a meaning in taking this field as an exponential of the generators?

Also, I don't understand which representation is taken into account for $T^a$ when we have the term,
$$\mathcal{L} = \frac{ v^2}{4}\operatorname{Tr}\big[\big(\partial_\mu\Sigma \big)^{\dagger}\big(\partial_\mu\Sigma \big)\big],$$
since it doesn't act on any given representation of the group.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/472637/embedding-of-su2-l-times-u1-y-into-su2-l-times-su2-r-in-electrowea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a meaning to take this field as an exponential function of the generators?

From your basic Lie group theory you presumably appreciate the logic of the [chiral model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_model) of the astounding Gürsey: in short,

- The projective coordinate ("pion") fields $\chi^a$ are in the Lie algebra, in representation $T^a$, often the fundamental.
- The exponentials $\Sigma$ you are asking about are in the Lie group generated by said algebra $T$, and *not* in the Lie algebra. Expanding in inverse *v* you see they include the identity matrix, so they are not expandable as a linear combination of generators, as you propose. If the *T* are hermitian, the $\Sigma$ are unitary. They transform in the group representation the $\chi$s transform in the algebra representation of. Specifically, $\Sigma \to L\Sigma R$, for *L* and *R* in the mutually commuting left- and right- SU(N)s, respectively.
- The left-invariant $\Sigma ^\dagger \partial_\mu \Sigma$  and right-invariant $\Sigma \partial_\mu \Sigma ^\dagger$ currents, nevertheless, ***are*** in the Lie algebra; this should be at the heart of your group theory and chiral model course.   They transform in the adjoint of the R and L groups respectively!

The lagrangian you wrote is "magically" invariant under *both* the *L* and the *R* groups, since, by the cyclicity of the trace and $\Sigma ^\dagger \partial \Sigma +  \partial \Sigma ^\dagger \Sigma    =\partial (\Sigma ^\dagger \Sigma  )=0$,
$$
\operatorname{Tr} \partial_\mu \Sigma^\dagger  \partial ^\mu \Sigma = \operatorname{Tr} \partial_\mu \Sigma^\dagger ~ ( \Sigma  \Sigma^\dagger) ~ \partial ^\mu \Sigma = -\operatorname{Tr} (\Sigma^\dagger\partial_\mu \Sigma) ~~ (\Sigma^\dagger \partial ^\mu \Sigma) \\ =
\operatorname{Tr} \Sigma  \partial_\mu \Sigma^\dagger \partial ^\mu \Sigma  \Sigma^\dagger = -\operatorname{Tr} (\Sigma\partial_\mu \Sigma^\dagger) ~~ (\Sigma \partial ^\mu \Sigma^\dagger). 
$$

You ***must*** verify all of the above statements for *N=2*, as your instructor has made you do, mindful of the algebra su(2) to group SU(2)
map you must have mastered, reminiscent of Euler's identity,
$$
\exp (i\theta \hat n\cdot \vec \sigma)= \cos\theta ~~1\!\! 1 + i\sin\theta ~ 
~ \hat n\cdot \vec \sigma.
$$

Comment: Ok now i see, we take the exponential because we want the identity, which is missing in a linear combination. I still don't understand which representation is chosen for the $T^a$. I know it must be the one parametrized by the $\chi$s, but is one actually chosen? Like the $\square$ or the Adj? I don't understand which one we choose in that lagrangian, if we choose one

Comment: Any one. Your text probably chooses the fundamental, like the Pauli matrices you checked for SU(2)…

Comment: The problem is i don't have a reference for this, our lecturer didn't gave us one and also covered this in like 15/20mn max. As i understand, to choose a representation is not required to actually compute things right? If i know the metric g of the SU(N) manifold, the term $g(\partial_{\mu}\Sigma^\dagger, \partial_{\mu}\Sigma)$ do not depend on the representation, or to do calculations i need one? (Like, the fundamental for instance)

Comment: Right. Try a QFT book, like the one by Schwartz…

Comment: Ok, thank you for the suggestion and for your help :)