# Lattice $SU(2)$ Higgs model in unitary gauge

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, symmetry-breaking, lattice-model, lattice-gauge-theory

I'm currently reading the book **Quantum Fields on a Lattice** by I. Montvay and G.Münster, and in section 6.1 they describe lattice actions for various higgs models. And I got confused at the moment where they describe the unitary gauge action for $SU(2)$-higgs theory.
In 6.16 they say that higgs field can be represented as $φ_x = ρ_xα_x$ , $ρ_x \ge 0$ , $α_x\in SU(2)$ and $φ_x^+φ_x=ρ_x^21$. Where $ρ_x$ is length of higgs field at given point, and $α_x$ is angular components of the higgs field.
And in 6.24 they define unitary gauge $α_x' = 1$ , $φ_x' = \begin{pmatrix} ρ_x & 0 \\ 0 & ρ_x \\ \end{pmatrix}$. Higgs field becomes a diagonal matrix with entries being higgs length(modulus), thus getting a preferred direction and breaking gauge symmetry.
But what is the meaning of this $ρ_x$ ? It is almost always non-zero, it can be equal to zero only if the Higgs field $φ_x$ itself at this point is equal to zero. And you can measure it without going to unitary gauge, because it's gauge invariant quantity. So what you should use to measure higgs VEV or higgs propagator for example?

Comment: Higgs here is combination of negative hypercharge doublet and original doublet into 2x2 matrix

Comment: @CosmasZachos I'm not sure what you mean. The $ρ$ we're discussing here is just that - a vector length, a square root of the sum of the squares of the four components.

Comment: Forget it. I just linked to the doublet complex vector language in case you were overly familiar with that, to the detriment of the matrix representation discussed here. Indeed, ρ is a real function, the sqrt of the determinant of φ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/473175/66086), up to language and normalizations. That is, your authors adopt the 2×2 hermitian matrix representation of the complex Higgs doublet $\phi$, by arraying it and its conjugate in entries of a transposed two vector,  (Longhitano's thesis):
$$
\varphi \equiv (\tilde{\phi}, \phi)=(i\tau_2 \phi^*, \phi). \tag{6.1,6.2}
$$
I have suppressed throughout the entirely superfluous subscripts *x*.

This matrix may be written as
$$
\varphi = \rho \alpha , \leadsto \\
\varphi^\dagger \varphi = \rho^2 \alpha^\dagger \alpha = \rho^2 \mathbb{I}, \tag{6.15, 6.16}
$$
since the *a*s are unitary and unimodular. The latter matrix is L- and hypercharge gauge invariant, since it is only variant under the global R, custodial, symmetry!

The *ρ* is the unshifted radial variable of the Higgs field, the *only* one uninvolved in the Goldstone phenomenon, basically the v.e.v. plus the "debris" Higgs particle excitation. Tastefully, the authors call it the *σ*, mapping it to the legendary O(4)/O(3) *σ*-model of Gell-Mann and Levy...  $\langle \rho^2\rangle= 1$ so $\langle \varphi^\dagger \varphi\rangle=   \mathbb{I}$.

In unitary gauge, $  \alpha =\mathbb{I}$, so
$\langle \varphi\rangle=  \mathbb{I}$.

Comment: All I am discussing here is the global L symmetry. Upon gauging, you gauge fix the pions/goldstons to 0 in unitary gauge. ρ is a scalar impervious to gauge transformations (and global L ones).

Comment: But then there's no reason to gauge fix (on lattice) because p is gauge-invariant

Comment: Of course: in this "radial" parameterization ρ is always gauge invariant... it is like the σ of the σ model....