# Custodial transformation in the SM Higgs

Tags: symmetry, field-theory, standard-model, group-theory

I am reading this [paper](https://lib-extopc.kek.jp/preprints/PDF/1990/9005/9005224.pdf) (or this [link](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.42.2127)), and I'm troubled by the custodial transformation. So, I will use the notations and equation labels appearing in this paper.

If we write the Higgs field into the four real components
$$
\Phi=\left(\begin{array}{c}
-\operatorname{Re} \phi_1 \\
\operatorname{Im} \phi_1 \\
\operatorname{Re} \phi_2 \\
\operatorname{Im} \phi_2
\end{array}\right) \tag{13}
$$
where $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are the complex components of $\Phi$ in the ordinary isospinor representation of the field,
$$
\left(\begin{array}{l}
\phi_1 \\
\phi_2
\end{array}\right) .
$$
The Higgs field potential under (13) has the $SO(4)$ symmetry, since
$$
\mathrm{SO}(4) \sim \mathrm{SU}(2)_{\text {isospin }} \times \mathrm{SU}(2)_{\text {custodial }}.
$$

We denote the isospin generator with $\mathbf{I}$, the custodial generator with $\mathbf{K}$. Then the isospin and custodial transformation  on the four vector $\Phi$ are
$$
\Phi_i \rightarrow e^{i \epsilon \cdot \mathbf{I}} \Phi_i=\left(e^{i \epsilon \cdot \mathbf{T}}\right)_{i j} \Phi_j \\
\Phi_i \rightarrow e^{i \epsilon' \cdot \mathbf{K}} \Phi_i=\left(e^{i \epsilon' \cdot \mathbf{T}^{\prime}}\right)_{i j} \Phi_j.
$$

So, now our goal is to calculate the 4 by 4 matrices $\mathbf{T}$ and $\mathbf{T^\prime}$. The calculation  can be done by recasting the transformation law of $\Phi$ in isospinor form. Where, for the isospin transformation,
$$
\left(\begin{array}{l}
\delta \phi_1 \\
\delta \phi_2
\end{array}\right)=i \epsilon \cdot \tau\left(\begin{array}{l}
\phi_1 \\
\phi_2
\end{array}\right)
$$
while, for the custodial transformation,
$$
\left(\begin{array}{l}
\delta \phi_1 \\
\delta \phi_2^*
\end{array}\right)=i \epsilon' \cdot \tau\left(\begin{array}{l}
\phi_1 \\
\phi_2^*
\end{array}\right) \tag{*} .
$$

My question is for the $(*)$ equation. Why does the custodial transformation in isospinor format take this  form?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: Link rot [preventative: doi, Carson et al](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.42.2127).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be a straight translation from this [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/482754/66086) answer, but I strongly suspect  [Carson et al., 1990](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.42.2127)  flipped a sign, at a deep level in their transition from a complex doublet to  the real quartet representation they actually use.  (They don't actually use this doublet/matrix representation in practice, and are merely meaning to connect to the readers' shared educational background, adjusting for their errant sign.)

I can explain your (*) equation, provided I insert a minus sign in front of $_1$ in it. You first observe the action of a weak isospin transformation with parameter $\vec \alpha$ on the complex doublet and its conjugate rep,
$$
\phi = \begin{pmatrix} \phi_1 \\ \phi_2 \end{pmatrix} \qquad 
\phi  \mapsto e^{i\vec{\alpha}\cdot \vec{\tau}/2} \phi  \\
\tilde \phi =i\tau_2 \phi^*= \begin{pmatrix} \phi^{*}_2 \\ -\phi_1^* \end{pmatrix} \qquad
\tilde \phi  \mapsto e^{i \vec{\alpha}\cdot \vec{\tau}/2}\tilde  \phi ~.$$

Thus, the 2×2  Higgs matrix is defined as a side-by-side juxtaposition of these two left-doublets serving as columns,
$$
H\equiv \sqrt{2}(\tilde\phi, \phi)=  \sqrt {2} \begin{pmatrix} \phi_2^{*} &\phi_1 \\ -\phi_1^* & \phi_2  \end{pmatrix}.
$$

It is then evident that it transforms by left *α* isospin and also by *manifestly* commuting right *β* custodial isorotations   *K*   as
$$  \bbox[yellow]{
 e^{i\vec{\alpha}\cdot \vec{\tau}/2}  \sqrt{2}(\tilde\phi  , \phi  )e^{i\vec{\beta}\cdot \vec{\tau}/2}  =  e^{i\vec{\alpha} \cdot \vec{\tau}/2}\sqrt {2} \begin{pmatrix} \phi_2^* &\phi_1  \\ -\phi_1^*  & \phi_2 \end{pmatrix}e^{i\vec{\beta}\cdot \vec{\tau}/2} = e^{i\vec{\alpha}\cdot \vec{\tau}/2} H   e^{i\vec{\beta}\cdot \vec{\tau}/2}  ~  . }
$$

Taking the adjoint of this equation and looking at the custodial action on the second column of $H^\dagger$, we see that
$$
 \begin{pmatrix} -\phi_1 \\ \phi_2^* \end{pmatrix} \qquad 
  \mapsto \qquad  e^{-i\vec{\beta}\cdot \vec{\tau}/2}   \begin{pmatrix} -\phi_1 \\ \phi_2^* \end{pmatrix} \tag{*} 
$$
with the sign mismatch mentioned.

As indicated, it is trivial to demonstrate the action of *I* commutes with the action of *K*, so these two groups do not "know" about each other, i.e. they are in direct product, hence SO(4).

You may also trivially confirm that
$$
\operatorname{Tr} H^\dagger H = 4 \phi^\dagger \phi = 4 \Phi^T \Phi,
$$
invariant under $\mathrm{SU}(2)_{\text {isospin }} \times \mathrm{SU}(2)_{\text {custodial }}$.

---

NB *Note added*

I mapped the custodial $\tau_2 \to T'_2$ on p 2132, and matched correctly *my* (*), not theirs, on the same page, to their quartet.  (Perhaps they meant to have
$\small \begin{pmatrix} \phi_2 \\ \phi_1^* \end{pmatrix}  \mapsto   e^{-i\vec{\beta}\cdot \vec{\tau}/2}   \begin{pmatrix} \phi_2 \\ \phi_1^* \end{pmatrix} $, instead?)

Comment: Hi professor, thank you very much! May I ask a related question in Carson et al.'s 1990 paper? In the third equation below equation (13), they say that the isospin transformation for the gauge fields is $\mathbf{A}^a \rightarrow e^{i \epsilon \cdot \mathbf{I}} \mathbf{A}^a=\left(e^{i \epsilon \cdot \Delta}\right)^{a b} \mathbf{A}^b$, where $(\Delta^a)^{bc}=-i\epsilon^{abc}$. I am troubled for this form. In gauge theory, we know the gauge field transforms like $A_\mu^a T^a\rightarrow U (A_\mu^a T^a)U^\dagger+ \frac{i}{g}U(\partial_\mu U^\dagger)$. And it seems that these two things don't match.

Comment: No hurry, thanks!

Comment: As stated at the beginning of sec II, they have fixed the gauge, and monitor the residual global symmetry.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Clear!